# read_sql_query() slower using ProcessPoolExecutor()

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite, concurrent.futures

I have about 1 million queries similar to the one below that I want to run on a local SQLite database of 30M rows and I'm looking to speed up. Running the query in SQLiteStudio takes 0.04s and running it through Pandas 0.075s :

```
starttime = timer()
con = sqlite3.connect(f"C:\\Users\\database.db")
query = "SELECT MIN(datetime), * FROM big_table " \
        "WHERE x = 1 AND y = 2 AND z = 3 " \
        "GROUP BY DATE(datetime), name)"
try:
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query, con=con)
finally:
    con.close()
print(f"Pandas query time: {timer()-starttime}")
```

If I try to speed up by multiprocessing with `ProccessPoolExecutor()` it seems to run bit faster, but suddenly the same queries take ~1.00s. I have 12 cores so thought I could expect ~12x the speed.

```py
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
                results = executor.map(multiprocessor, queries)

def multiprocessor(query):
    starttime = timer()
    con = sqlite3.connect(f"C:\\Users\\database.db")
    try:
        df = pd.read_sql_query(query, con=con)
    finally:
        con.close()
    print(f"Multiprocessed pandas query time: {timer()-starttime}")
```

- SQLiteStudio time: 0.04s
- Pandas query time: 0.075s
- Multiprocessed Pandas query time: 1.00s

Why does the query run faster through an IDE like SQLiteStudio than Pandas? And why are my queries slowing down when run through `ProcessPoolExecutor()`? Is there anything I can do to speed this up?

P.S.: The query shown is simplified, but essentially it's getting the first occurrence of each name per day. I'm open to suggestions on how to improve that as well.

Comment: You said MySQL, but your code is using sqlite3.  Which one is it?  The answers are very different.  I cannot imagine using sqlite3 with 30 million rows.  Sqlite was designed to be small and simple -- it was not designed for extreme performance.  It sounds like you really need a database server.

Comment: `I have about 1 million queries` Why do you have a million queries? Can you write it as one big query? That's usually faster.

Comment: @TimRoberts, sorry you're correct. I'm using SQLite not MySQL. I've corrected my post. I have looked at sqlalchemy and postgreSQL, but performance-wise it didn't sound like switching to those would make much of an improvement. Is that true? Do you recommend switching to something else?

Comment: @NickODell, I essentially have ~1M different tests with a combination of parameters that I'm testing.  Each test might only return 50-200 rows. I could write a broader query that gets a larger number of rows, but then I'd still have to filter it down to the individual tests on the pandas side. I've heard it's slower to filter out data in Dataframes than it is in to just do it in SQL queries.

Comment: `sqlachemy` is just a front-end.  It isn't a database.  PostgreSQL is a database server, designed for large datasets.  But even so, if you're moving multiple megabytes, that's going to take time.